# Set cell borders as dashed in tcpdf WriteHTML

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Hi i want to make the border of table cells as dashed lines in TCPDF writehtml()... I have tried using border=1 for tables but only a thick border comes .. also i have tried using css like  `style="border-style: dashed;border-width: 1px; "` however the border remains the same... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a8458280d15b73d3baffb28eebe2d9246), if you’d use `writeHTMLCell()`, the 6th argument represents the border style. A dashed border would look like:

```
TCPDF::writeHTMLCell(
    …,
    array(
        'LRTB' => array(
            'width' => 1, // careful, this is not px but the unit you declared
            'dash'  => 1,
            'color' => array(0, 0, 0)
        )
    ),
    …
);
```

[This example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_017.phps) ([demo](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_017.pdf)) helped me a lot creating tables in PHP with `MultiCell()` instead of HTML.

Comment: the problem is that i havea a lot or rows and columns and the html is rather complex at times. SO i cannot go for WriteHTMLcell.. And i have some 105+ pages to be converted to pdf all with dynamic data.. so i cant go for multicell too.. I have concentrated in rendering the html with correct alignment and use the same thing to render pdf....

Comment: What about an application that converts HTML to PDF? There’s a good one available written in Qt, it uses vectors and even supports canvas. Can’t remember the name though.

Answer (score 1):

`style="border:1px dashed;"` This is working for me ....

Comment: can you please post the full html?? Did you use it for <td> or <tr>?