# tcpdf WriteHTML dashed borders

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I have an HTML document, which consists of 100s of rows with 3 columns each. Basic structure is like the following:

```
 <table style="padding: 10px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-style: 1px dotted; font-size: 10px">
      <tr>
           <td style="vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;border: 1px dashed black"></td>
           <td style="vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;border: 1px dashed black"></td>
           <td style="vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;border: 1px dashed black"></td>
      </tr>
      ...
 </table>
```

I want this table's borders to be in dashed format. However, it doesn't work. It keeps giving me weird results where the border is black with blurry gray spread around it (almost looks like a shadow).

I am using TCPDF 6.2.12.

How should I set this up?

Comment: Please check this link:https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_035/

Comment: Will this Line Style work with `WriteHTML` function?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352500/set-cell-borders-as-dashed-in-tcpdf-writehtml

Comment: As per the suggestion "style="border:1px dashed;" will work.Please try & let us know.

Comment: Nope. This is what I get for dashed border: http://imgur.com/a/bPvFx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does TCPDF ignore my inline CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395171/why-does-tcpdf-ignore-my-inline-css)

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug that has been introduced:, it never used to be present. `border-bottom: dashed 1px;` used to look fine, now it's grey thick and speckled `border-bottom: dashed 1px black;` simply isn't dashed